# Is there a shortkey or command for the "Clear results" function

Tags: stata, shortcut

There's no shortkey right to the `Clear results` menu item in the `Edit` menu. I would like to be able to clear the main screen without using the mouse. I'm using Stata 13 on Windows 2008 Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't strike me as a programming question; nevertheless from Stata 13 there is a `cls` command for precisely this purpose.

[Users of all versions can see that documented here.](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?whatsnew12to13)

Comment: Thanks. Would you say it makes sense to migrate to stats.SE?

Comment: No; it would be **less** appropriate there! The best site for Stata questions remains Statalist. I've answered this question as I think the answer might interest people following Stata here; without I think outrageous inconsistency I am also flagging that it's not a programming question in any strong sense.